# Java - Generate download from byte[] using Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv

The problem is that I have a byte[] and I wanted to create a downloadable CSV file after my app process some information. I'm using the Google App Engine (GAE) and it doesn't allow any I/O. I was wondering if is possible make the byte[] downloadable using servlets. If that's not possible, what would be the best approach? I tried to use the GAE Blobstore, but it's all deprecated and all my tests didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! My workaround was to use response headers.
First step has to convert byte[] into String. And then I did this:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();             
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=datafile.csv");
out.println("my,CSV,data");
```

Done! Problem solved.